# How should I use Git for different modules of a project?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'd like to create my own smart home system and would like to use Git for project tracking. The project is going to be divided into modules for the Raspberry Pi, Arduino, and web interface.

How should I structure my project? These are the ideas that I have:

- Separate repo for each module
- Separate folder for each module in one repo
- Using submodules
- Using orphan branches

I've never used submodules or orphan branches before. A few comments have said that submodules and orphan branches add complexity, which I'd like to avoid if they outweigh the benefits.

I'd really appreciate any advice on this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git a repository represents an autonomous and versionable software module.

So, you should create a repo for each software component, and aggregate them by submodule if required.